# LINQ Query (Group BY)?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following object:

```
public class Address { public string city; public string state; public string country; }
```

If I have a list of addresses how would I use LINQ to get a list of counts where the city, state, and country match.

So my result might look something like this:

- "princeton" "nj" "usa" 122
- "austin" "tx" "usa" 44
- "la" "ca" "usa" 1
- "princton" "na" "uk" 3
- ....

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Went one step further than Marc's answer (which he edited before I posted!). LOL

```
var qry = from addr in addresses
          group addr by new { addr.city, addr.state, addr.country } into grp
          select new
          {
            city = grp.Key.city,
            state = grp.Key.state,
            country = grp.Key.country,
            count = grp.Count(),
          };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var qry = addresses.GroupBy(addr => new { addr.city, addr.state, addr.country});
```

then you can do (for example):

```
foreach(var row in qry) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} \t {3}",
                 row.Key.city, row.Key.state, row.Key.country, row.Count());
}
```

i.e. the `.Key` of each group is the composite `new { addr.city, addr.state, addr.country}`, and each group is also `IEnumerable<Address>`. Note that for database queries you should tell it your entire intent up front, for example:

```
var qry = from addr in db.Addresses
          group addr by new { addr.city, addr.state, addr.country} into grp
          select new {
              grp.Key.city, grp.Key.state,
              grp.Key.country, Count = grp.Count()
          };
```

so that it has the best possible chance to do a sensible query (not n+1).

Answer (score 1):

This is what i tried(In LINQPAD) and it works well (Similar to Enigmativity' Answer ):

```
void Main()
{

    List<Address>   lst = new List<Address>();
    lst.Add(new Address{ city = "ny", state = "cy", country = "india"});
    lst.Add(new Address{ city = "ny", state = "cy", country = "india"});
    lst.Add(new Address{ city = "by", state = "cy", country = "india"});
    lst.Add(new Address{ city = "ny", state = "fr", country = "india"});
        var qry = from addr in lst
        group addr by new { addr.city, addr.state, addr.country } into grp
        select new
        {
            city = grp.Key.city,
            state = grp.Key.state,
            country = grp.Key.country,
            count = grp.Count(),
        };
        qry.Dump();
}
public class Address { public string city; public string state; public string country; }
```

Output:

```
ny cy india 2

by cy india 1

ny fr india 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about grouping in LINQ in this article - http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/querysamples.html. It can be useful for you.